# Rspec: How to test recursion?

Tags: ruby, recursion, mocking, rspec

I'd like to test that a method is called recursively with a specific argument.

My approach:

```
class Recursable
  def rec(arg)
    rec(7) unless arg == 7
  end
end

describe Recursable do
  it "should recurse" do
    r = Recursable.new('test')
    r.should_receive(:rec).with(0).ordered
    r.should_receive(:rec).with(7).ordered
    r.rec(0)
  end
end
```

Unexpectedly, RSpec fails with:

```
expected :rec with (7) once, but received it 0 times
```

Any idea what's wrong with my approach? How to test for effective recursion with a specific argument?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem with your test as it is now is that you are stubbing away the method you are trying to test. `r.should_receive(:rec)` is replacing `r#rec` with a stub, which of course doesn't ever call `r.rec(7)`.

A better approach would be to simply test that the result of the initial method call is correct. It shouldn't strictly matter whether or not the method recurses, iterates, or phones a friend, as long as it gives the right answer in the end.

Comment: Ah, okay. Oh, well! I am trying to find a bug - the method does return a wrong value (it is more complicated than depicted here). I thought I could test each part of it in order to narrow down the problem space. It gets more complicated with each level of recursion and it would have been nice to test whether the recursion is executed correctly.

Comment: In other words: Don't test the implementation, test the effect the code has. Great answer!

Answer (score 2):

Often if you need to test recursion it is a code smell; you probably should split the method into different responsibilities or something.

But some times you just need to add some basic checks on your recursion.
You can do it with Rspec `and_call_original`:

```
it "should recurse" do
  r = Recursable.new('test')
  r.should_receive(:rec).with(0).ordered.and_call_original
  r.should_receive(:rec).with(7).ordered.and_call_original
  r.rec(0)
end
```

Normally `should_receive` will just stub the real method, that's why the recursion doesn't work. With `and_call_original` the stubbed method (that contains the test checks) will also call the original method implementation, that will perform the recursion as expected.